# How to retreive invoice details from Google Api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk, google-reseller-api

We are selling Google Apps to clients (Reseller). At the beginning of each month, we are receiving an invoice from Google Cloud GSuite by email.

Inside there is a detailed list of rendered services:

```
Example: 
domain1.com    EUR 28,00
domain2.com    EUR  2.80
------------------------
total              30.80
```

We want to push these details into our billing system to create invoices for our customers.

I already had a look at various google APIs but none of them seems to fit the bill (pun intended).

I'm looking for the right google API endpoint to talk to.

Comment: I am not aware of an endpoint for this purpose other than the Billing API. Google recommends sinking your billing data to BigQuery and then running queries to obtain billing details. Combine this with Google Sheets and you can create an automated invoicing system.

Comment: I just realized that this post has not been answered. I'm sorry. Thanks for your advice! I'll follow this lead and see where it will bring me.